# Import contents of specific folder into iTunes using Applescript

Tags: applescript, itunes

I have created an Applescript that will, with one click, add the contents of a specific folder on my hard drive to iTunes (I really want to avoid using the iTunes organisational system).

#### Applescript

```
tell application "iTunes"
  set theFolder to ("Macintosh HD:Temp to be Listened to:Temp on iPod:")
  set with_subfolders to true --list subfolders or not (recursion)   
  set parent_folder to theFolder
end tell

tell application "System Events"
  set item_list to parent_folder
end tell

tell application "iTunes"
  add contents of parent_folder to user playlist "Temp on iPod"
end tell
```

However, it only imports into iTunes the files from the top level/parent folder.
I want to include files from the folders in the parent folder.

Is there a way I can get it to be recursive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to get all files from a folder, since `iTunes` does this automatically and recursively from a folder.

Just add the **parent** folder, like this:

```
set parent_folder to "Macintosh HD:Temp to be Listened to:Temp on iPod:" as alias
tell application "iTunes"
    add parent_folder to user playlist "Temp on iPod"
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution #1: Using `entire contents` of the Finder - not very fast

```
set theFolder to "Macintosh HD:Temp to be Listened to:Temp on iPod:"
tell application "Finder" to set filesToAdd to files of entire contents of folder theFolder as alias list
tell application "iTunes" to add filesToAdd to user playlist "Temp on iPod"
```

Solution #2 : Using Spotlight - very fast, but the volume must be indexed.

```
set theFolder to "/Temp to be Listened to/Temp on iPod"
set fileList to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind -onlyin " & quoted form of theFolder & space & quoted form of "kMDItemContentTypeTree == '*public.audio*'")
set filesToAdd to {}
repeat with aFile in fileList
    set end of filesToAdd to POSIX file aFile as alias
end repeat
tell application "iTunes" to add filesToAdd to user playlist "Temp on iPod"
```